# how to get largeTitle on current vc, but small title on vc being pushed to?

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uistoryboard, preferslargetitles

I have a simple "more" screen where I want to have a `largeTitle`. 
I have several entries in a static table view which are leading to other view controllers. 
I want to have the large title in the "more" screen, but not in the screens pushed to. 
Either are all of the titles large or all small. How do I do it?
I am using the storyboard.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the detail vc set the following:

```
self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
```

If you access the `navigationItem` of the `navigationController`, it will change all detail vc, but if you access the `navigationItem` of the detailVC, it will only change the current title in the `navigationBar`.

You cannot do that in Storyboard, because you cannot click on the `navigationBar` itself in the detail vc.

More information available in a [WWDC video from 2017](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/204/?time=268).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
```

in your second View Controller?

Comment: no, I thought I could do all of that large title behavior in storyboard...

Comment: I don' think that's possible.

Comment: I tried your suggestion in code. It sets all titles to small, because it sets it on the navigationController. This is not what I want. I want to have a large title on the first vc and a small one on the second vc, pretty much like it is done throughout iOS.

Comment: try to set it in your normal view controller.

Comment: regardless where I set it, it is the same what I can do in storyboard. If I select the navigationController (screenshot, most left vc), I can set this property. On all other vc I cannot set this property, because there is only one navigationController.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is only one `navigation controller` which stacks all your views,
you can try to write

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
```

in the `viewWillApear` method of the second viewController
and on `viewWillDisappear` you can change it again to

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

Comment: is there a better way? It seems like this is rather a hack than the way Apple does it.

Comment: Actually this is not a hack, this is also used to change navigation bar color of the viewController when its pushed and change it back when its popped. You will find this practice if you search for changing the navigation bar color of pushed viewControler. Because there is only one navigation stack which is stacking all the views